# Write only few columns of pyspark dataframe to a snowflake table

Tags: pyspark

I have a pyspark data frame as below:

```
>>> l = [('XYZ', '324 NW', ‘VA’), ('XYZ, '323 NW', ‘VA’), (‘CVB’, '314 NW', ‘VA’)]
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame(l, ('Name', 'Address', 'State')) 
Name    Address State
XYZ 324 NW  VA
ABC 323 NW  VA
CVB 314 NW  VA

CREATE or replace TABLE TEST
(
    NAME VARCHAR(50),
    ADDRESS VARCHAR(50),
    STATE VARCHAR(50));
```

When I try to write this entire pyspark dataframe to a TEST table using the below pyspark code, it works perfectly fine

```
df.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).OPTIONS(**snowflake_options).option(“dbtable”, ‘TEST).mode(‘append’).save()
```

How do I write only 'Address' and 'State' column to snowflake table ignoring ‘Name’ column?

I also tried below code but it keeps giving me invalid syntax

```
df.write.format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME).OPTIONS(**snowflake_options)
.option(“dbtable”, ‘TEST)
.option("columnmap", Map("Address" -> "ADDRESS", "State" -> "STATE").toString())
.mode(‘append’).save()
```

Comment: `df.select('Address', 'State').write...` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just select 2 columns you wanted to save

```py
(df
    .select('Address', 'State') ## add this
    .write
    .format(SNOWFLAKE_SOURCE_NAME)
    .OPTIONS(**snowflake_options)
    .option('dbtable', 'TEST')
    .mode('append')
    .save()
)
```

Comment: I am getting error saying number of columns in file(2) does not match that of a corresponding table (3)

Comment: This is still a persistent issue from Snowflake.

Comment: you don’t want to write name but name is a column in snowflake, how does that works?